# UIView Animations with Objective-C Blocks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiview, objective-c-blocks

I have been playing around with the two different ways of doing `UIView` animations: begin/commit and Blocks.

I have noticed that the `beginAnimations:context:` / `commitAnimations` way of doing things is nicely asynchronous, keeping the UI free while the animation is running.

However, I also noticed that the `animateWithDuration:animations:completion` way seems to block the UI, making it unresponsive while the animation is running.

I thought one of the main points of using blocks was to achieve asynchronous execution easily. Why does the blocks variant of the `UIView` animarions block the UI while the begin/commit variant does not?

**Edit:**

My question originally assumed that the blocks animation was a synchronous operation and blocked the UI. As it transpired from Jeff Kelly's answer, that this isn't the case. My original assumption was incorrect, the blocks animation is not synchronous. See Jeff's answer for the details.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you using the right `UIView` class method? If you use `+animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`, you can specify a bitmask of options. One of the possible options is `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`, which sounds like just what you want.

Comment: Interesting. You're right, that method does allow user interaction via the options. UIView has several class methods related to animating, the one you specify seems to be the most specific, while the other seems to be convenience methods which boil down to the one you mentioned in the end. I guess the question really should be, why isn't user interaction enabled by default as it is with the begin/commit methods? And I imagine we'll never know the answer...

Comment: @Jasarien: you don't necessarily *want* to have user interaction enabled, especially if that user interaction can itself trigger more animation. The safest way is to disable user interaction during animation - I'm more surprised that `begin/commit` enables it by default.

Comment: That may be a valid point, however, its been that way since the SDK was released with iOS v 2.0. Everyone using UIView animations with begin/commit will be used to user interaction being enabled (as I was) and *should* know to take the necessary precautions if they require it to be disabled while the animation runs.

Comment: If it was mentioned in the documentation for the less specific methods that user interaction is disabled while the animation runs, I wouldn't be here asking the question ;)

Comment: For what it’s worth, when iOS 4.0 first came out, the *opposite* was true: block-based animations allowed user interaction. Apple changed it, and this is now the default.